# How to override a function of a third party / custom plugin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

From Magento 2 (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

> Prioritizing plugins
>
> The sortOrder property for plugins determine when their before, after,
>   or around methods get called when several plugins are observing the
>   same method.
>
> The prioritization rules for ordering plugins:
>
> Prior to execution of the observed method, plugins will be executed
>   from lowest to greatest sortOrder.
>
> During each plugin execution, the current plugin’s before method is
>   executed first. After the before plugin is executed, the current
>   plugin’s around method will wrap and execute the next plugin or
>   observed method. Following the execution of the observed method,
>   plugins will be executed from greatest to lowest sortOrder.
>
> During each plugin execution, the current plugin will first finish
>   executing its around method. When the around method is complete, the
>   plugin executes its after method before moving on to the next plugin.

However, I want to stop / remove a process in a function of a third party / custom plugin. So I don't want it runs if a condition broken. It means I don't want the function can run in some situations. So how can I override that function to do that ?

I can create a plugin has a method with lower priority than the method, then it can be run earlier than the method. But as I understand, after my function runs then the function runs too. I can not stop it to run as Magento states.

More details about the function I want to override:

```
 public function aroundSavePaymentInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        $email,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    )
    {
        $orderAttributes = $billingAddress->getOrderAttributes(); => It will be fail if there is no $billingAddress, so I want to add a check to make sure if we have $billingAddress, then the process will be called, if not then return.
        $this->sessionHelper->setOrderAttributesToSession($cartId, $orderAttributes);
        return $proceed($cartId,  $email, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    }
```

Please suggest some solutions that you may have, I am really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's third party plugin and you have control over the installation then i think fixing the original issue in that module is the best approach.

If that is not doable for some reason, i remember reading somewhere that you should always call $proceed() in around plugins so other plugins can run. Based on that i would say that if you dont call $proceed, but perform the logic directly in your around plugin, then the problematic plugin wont run.

I haven't tested this, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are just normal classes. You can create plugin for plugin method.